An integral using Mathematica or otherwise
Consider the unit square integral $$I=\int_{(0,1)^5}\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)u(1-u)v(1-v)w(1-w)}{(1-(1-xyuv)w)^2}\ dxdydudvdw$$
Using Mathematica or otherwise I need a closed form of I, possibly in terms of the Riemann zeta function.
I tried the following code in Wolfram cloud:
 Integrate [ 
 x* (1 - x)* y* (1 - y)* u*(1-u)*v*(1-v)*w*(1-w)/(1 - 
(1-x*y*u*v)*w)^2,{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]

Unfortunately I am getting the answer as "aborted" and that it exceeds the time limit for the plan. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Is the denominator squared? It differs from the formula above.

Fold the integrals:  $$f1=\int  x* (1 - x)/(1 -
(1-xyu*v)*w)^2 \ dx $$, evaluate the limits and than do $$\int f1 \ y\  (1-y) \ dy$$. Yo will encounter problems with $w=1, x=0$ etc

Using:
$$\sum _{\alpha =0}^{-A} \binom{-A}{\alpha } (u v w x y)^{\alpha } (1-w)^{-A-\alpha }=(1-w+u v w x y)^{-A}$$
where: A=2 Then:
func0 = (1 - u)  u  (1 - v)  v  (1 - w)  w  (1 - x)  x  (1 - y)  y*
Binomial[-A, \[Alpha]]*(u  v  w  x  y)^\[Alpha]*(1 - w)^(-A - \[Alpha]) // PowerExpand
func1 = Integrate[func0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
func2 = Sum[func1[[1]], {\[Alpha], 0, -A}] // FullSimplify
FullSimplify[Limit[func2, A -> 2] // Quiet]

(*-146 + \[Pi]^4/5 + 88 Zeta[3] + 20 Zeta[5] *)

N[%, 50]
(*0.0013807877121830890923344798893047984059292505392422*)

Looks like the same answer gives @Vaclav Kotesovec.

Thats really nice. Thanks a lot

I tried it with 2 and 3 variables
 Integrate[x*(1 - x)*w*(1 - w)/(1 - (1 - x)*w)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
 (* 5 - \[Pi]^2/2 *)

 Integrate[x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*w*(1 - w)/(1 - (1 - x*y)*w)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
 (* 2 (-6 + 5 Zeta[3]) *)
 

The last calculation took 2 minutes. For 4 or 5 variables much more time will be needed.
UPDATE
For 4 variables I got the result
 Integrate[x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*u*(1 - u)*w*(1 - w)/(1 - (1 - x*y*u)*w)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
 (* Integrate[(1/x^2)*((-1 + x) * (12*x + 4*(-2*x + (-1 + x)*Log[1 - x]) * Log[x] + (4*(-1 + x) + (4 + x)*Log[x])*  PolyLog[2, x] - 2*(4 + x)*  PolyLog[3, x])), {x, 0, 1}] *)

This can be determined numerically
 N[%, 60]
 (* 0.00561141445030485596277453183178911513759783187848690425415362 *)

and the constant can be identified as
 N[41 - \[Pi]^4/10 - 26 Zeta[3], 60]
 (* 0.00561141445030485596277453183178911513759783187848690425415362 *)

For 5 variables I got the following complicated integral
 Integrate[x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*u*(1 - u)*v*(1 - v)*w*(1 - w)/(1 - (1 - x*y*u*v)*w)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]

 (* (1/6)*Integrate[(1/(x^2*y^2))*(-1 + x)*(-1 + y)*(5*Pi^2 - 72*x*y - 
 5*Pi^2*x*y + 48*x*y*Log[x] + 48*x*y*Log[y] - 6*Log[x]*Log[1 - x*y] + 
 6*x*y*Log[x]*Log[1 - x*y] - 6*Log[y]*Log[1 - x*y] + 
 6*x*y*Log[y]*Log[1 - x*y] - 6*(1 - x*y + (4 + x*y)*Log[x*y])*
 PolyLog[2, x*y] + 30*(-1 + x*y)*PolyLog[2, 1 - x*y] + 
 48*PolyLog[3, x*y] + 12*x*y*PolyLog[3, x*y]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] *)

Numerically
 (* 0.0013807877121831639339 *)

But only 14-15 digits of this value are valid.
I have found a conjectural symbolic value of this constant:
 N[-146 + 88*Zeta[3] + 18*Zeta[4] + 20*Zeta[5], 60]
 (* 0.00138078771218308909233447988930479840592925053924217549732231 *)

To verify this, the numerical value would need to be calculated more accurately.
UPDATE 2 I tried
NIntegrate[-(1/(6 x^2 y^2)) (-1 + x) (-1 + y) (72 x y + 5 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + x y) + 
6 (Log[x*y]) (-8 x y + (1 - x y) Log[1 - x y]) + 
6 (1 - x y + (4 + x y) (Log[x*y])) PolyLog[2, x y] - 
30 (-1 + x y) PolyLog[2, 1 - x y] - 
12 (4 + x y) PolyLog[3, x y]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "InterpolationPointsSubdivision" -> False}]

With an error message
(* During evaluation of NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 18 recursive bisections in y near ...
 NIntegrate obtained 0.0013807877121830890959055260156412830847466394016003137578401799154348063120626547224840777709335762246630371148`110.
 and 5.0549632677670460303461898987257465737053265991691771657567115534696444431541293721976965612476328957244441785`110.*^-17 for the integral and error estimates. *)

but 20 digits now are correct!

($+1$) Thanks. But I need a closed form for $I$

Thanks. Can't we make any change of variable? It might help?

I seem to have found a closed form.
